# What is the smallest and fastest way to transpile TypeScript to JavaScript in the browser?

Tags: typescript, vercel

I have a unique use case for the [typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript) library where I need to transpile user-submitted TypeScript into JavaScript in a V8 runtime. I can use the `transpile` function provided in the typescript library, but this brings that single functions bundle size to 1.7 MB. I need this function to be under 1MB.

Is a smaller way to transpile typescript in the browser?

Comment: To what degree does type correctness matter for you? You might be able to use a smaller library to transpile by purely removing the type annotations, but you would lose compile-time type checking.

Comment: "_I need this function to be under 1MB_": Can you explain this more precisely? Why this arbitrary limit? Do you mean that you want to include up to 1MB of code into some bundle? What about using UMD modules in `<script>` tags in your page? Because of caching, the size would not matter on subsequent loads. etc...

Comment: @jsejcksn This code in running in a Vercel Edge Function, a sort-of cloud function environment. Vercel sets the bundle limit for these functions to 1MB.

Comment: @JeffBowman That would actually suffice. The type-checking is actually done in a different system, so by the time I hit compile there would be no type errors. However, writing a type-annotation remover seems like a nightmare...might be the best option though.

Comment: @PeterEdmonds I ask because it means that tools like [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io/content-types/#typescript) are eligible. "esbuild has built-in support for parsing TypeScript syntax and discarding the type annotations. However, esbuild does not do any type checking so you will still need to run `tsc -noEmit` in parallel with esbuild to check types." Unfortunately [esbuild is likely too big too](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/836), but suffice to say that for TS-to-JS transpilation you might have more options if type-checking isn't strictly required.